# Strange occurance when editing model attribute

Tags: django, model, attributes

My Models look like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
  ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    attr = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

From the shell, I see the following behavior:

```
>>> m1.model2_set.all()[0].attr += 1
>>> m1.model2_set.all()[0].attr
1
>>> m2 = m1.model2_set.all()[0]
>>> m2.attr += 1
2
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are retrieving the same Model2 instance from your db. m1 and m2 seem to have the same Model2 attached to it, which you retrieve by `model2_set.all()[0]`. You could verify this like:

```
>>> m2.model2_set.all()[0] == m1.model2_set.all()[0] # should be true
```